# ¿Por qué me sale undefined en una vista de blade.php en laravel?

Tags: eloquent, variables, laravel-6

Estoy intentando hacer la vinculación de un 3er. formulario que en este caso es la de vehículos, para ello genero el controlador VehiculoController.php con la siguiente información:

```js
<? php

namespace App\ Http\ Controllers;

use Illuminate\ Http\ Request;
use App\ Vehiculo;

class VehiculoController extends Controller {
  public
  function create() {

    $titulo = "Formulario de Vehículo";

    return view('vehiculo.create', [
      'titulo' => $titulo
    ]);
  }

  public
  function save(Request $request) {

    $vehiculo = Vehiculo::all();

    $validate = $this - > validate($request, [
      'propietario_id' => 'integer|required',
      'conductor_id' => 'integer|required',
      'placa' => 'required|string|max:25|unique:vehiculos,placa',
      'color' => 'required|string|max:25',
      'marca' => 'required|string|max:40',
      'tipo_vehiculo' => 'required|string|max:30'
    ]);

    $propietario_id = $request - > input('propietario_id');
    $conductor_id = $request - > input('conductor_id');
    $placa = $request - > input('placa');
    $color = $request - > input('color');
    $marca = $request - > input('marca');
    $tipo_vehiculo = $request - > input('tipo_vehiculo');


    $vehiculo = new Vehiculo();

    $vehiculo - > propietario_id = $propietario_id;
    $vehiculo - > conductor_id = $conductor_id;
    $vehiculo - > placa = $placa;
    $vehiculo - > color = $color;
    $vehiculo - > marca = $marca;
    $vehiculo - > tipo_vehiculo = $tipo_vehiculo;

    $vehiculo - > save();

    return redirect() - > route('home') -
      > with(['message' => 'Los datos guardados correctamente!!']);

  }

}
```

Una vez hecho esto tengo también el modelo que contiene la siguiente información, `vehiculo.php`:

```js
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehiculo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vehiculos';

    // Relación Many to One
    public function propietario(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Propietario', 'propietario_id');
    }

    // Relación Many to One
    public function conductor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conductor', 'conductor_id');
    }
}
?>
```

Y acontinuación, en la vista tengo el archivo create.blade.php con la siguiente información:

```html
@use vehiculo; @extends('layouts.app') @section('content')

<div class="container">

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10">

      @include ('includes.message')

      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">{{ $titulo }}</h5>



        <div class="card-body">
          <form method="POST" action="{{ route('vehiculo.save') }}">
            @csrf {{--ACÁ ESTÁ EL ERROR POR EL QUE NO ME PERMITE CONTINUAR LO QUE ESTÁ EN value="..." --}}
            <input type="hidden" name="propietario_id" value="{{'@'.$vehiculos->propietario->id }}" /> {{--
            <input type="hidden" name="conductor_id" value="{{ $vehiculo->conductor_id }}" />--}}



            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="cedula" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Placa</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="cedula" type="text" class="form-control @error('cedula') is-invalid @enderror" name="cedula" required autocomplete="cedula" autofocus /> @error('cedula')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span> @enderror
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="color" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Color</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="color" type="text" class="form-control @error('color') is-invalid @enderror" name="color" required autocomplete="color" /> @error('color')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span> @enderror
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="marca" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Marca</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="marca" type="text" class="form-control @error('marca') is-invalid @enderror" name="marca" required autocomplete="marca" /> @error('marca')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span> @enderror
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="tipo_vehiculo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Tipo de Vehículo</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="tipo_vehiculo" type="text" class="form-control @error('tipo_vehiculo') is-invalid @enderror" name="tipo_vehiculo" required autocomplete="tipo_vehiculo" /> @error('tipo_vehiculo')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span> @enderror
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Registro
                                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Estas son las rutas que le di en el archivo web.php del proyecto

```
// VEHÍCULO
Route::get('info-vehiculo', 'VehiculoController@create')->name('vehiculo.create');
Route::post('/vehiculo/save', 'VehiculoController@save')->name('vehiculo.save');
```

El siguiente reporte es lo que me genera como resultado

[image: Error que me aparece en la pantalla]

Comment: estás seguro que la variable es `$vehiculos` en vez de `vehiculo`?

Comment: Sea $vehiculos  o $vehiculo me sigue generando el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Hay alguien que me puedda ayudar con mi consulta o si porloscerros me puede ayudar? Le agradezco infinitamente, es que no tengo claro el tema y quiero ver qué estoy haciendo mal; Les agradezco infinitamente sus respuestas.

Comment: Típicamente tendrías que enviar esa variable del controlador a la vista. Por ej: `return view('vehiculo.create', [ 'titulo' => $titulo, 'vehiculo' => Vehiculo::find($id) ]);`. Pero no entiendo bien que estás tratando de hacer, si es un formulario para crear un vehículo, no entiendo por qué intentas acceder a esa variable en la vista